# Is this the correct way of equalising exponents of two different numbers according to the IEEE-754 standard?

Tags: c, ieee-754, exponent

**I have left out the mantissa and the sign bit as well as handling sub-normals, infinity, NaN, -0.0. I just wanted to focus on the exponent first and then the rest.**

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    
    #define N 23
    
    int binary(int n);
    int exp_diff(int exp1, int exp2);
```

**Structure of 32 bits one for the sign, 8 for the exponent and 23 for the mantissa**

```
    union{
        
        unsigned int result;
    
        struct {
            unsigned int mantissa: 23;
            unsigned int exponent: 8;
            unsigned int sign: 1;
        }value;
    }fps;
    
    
    int main(void)
    {
        int num1 = 3;
        int num2 = 5;
        int exp1 = 0;
        int exp2 = 0;
        
        exp1 = binary(num1);
        exp2 = binary(num2);
         
        fps.value.exponent = 127 + exp_diff(exp1,exp2);
         
         printf("%08x\n", fps.result);
         
         return 0;
    }
```

**Converting the value into binary and returning the exponent**

```
    int binary(int n)
    {   
        int i = 0;
        int remainder = 0;
        int a[N] = {0};
        
        while(n > 0){
            a[i++] = n % 2;
            n /= 2;
        }
        return i - 1;
    }
```

**Equalizing the exponents by finding if epx1 is less than exp2 vice versa**

```
    int exp_diff(int exp1, int exp2)
    {
         if(exp1 < exp2)
            return exp2 - exp1;
         else if(exp2 < exp1)
            return exp1 - exp2;
        
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be a bit clearer to rename `N` to something like `MANTISSA_NBITS` and then use it in the actual bitfield?

Comment: Your `exp_diff` needs a `return 0` at the bottom. Or, just eliminate the `else if` and do: `if (exp1 < exp2) return exp2 - exp1; else return exp1 - exp2;`

Comment: In `binary()`, I don't quite get what the `a[N]` array is used for; the value is set, but never used, so maybe all you really need is the `i++`.  Have you compiled your code with max compiler warnings (this probably would have pointed out the item pointed out by @CraigEstey as well).

Answer (score 0):

Accessing the internal fields of a floating-point representation using bit fields is problematic, as the C standard leaves implementations a lot of flexibility about how bit fields are laid out. A better method is to use bit shifting and masking operations. Assuming `float` is 32 bits and `<stdint.h>` is included:

```
typedef struct { unsigned sign, exponent, significand; } FloatFields;

FloatFields DecodeFloat(float x)
{
    uint32_t u;
    memcpy(&u, &x, sizeof u);
    return (FloatFields) {
        u >> 31,
        u >> 23 & 0xff,
        u       & 0x7fffff,
    };
}

float EncodeFloat(FloatFields Fields)
{
    uint32_t u = Fields.sign << 31 | Fields.exponent << 23 | Fields.significand;
    float f;
    memcpy(&f, &u, sizeof f);
    return f;
}
```

Regarding the code `fps.value.exponent = 127 + exp_diff(exp1,exp2);`, it is not clear that it does anything useful. It provides the encoding for an exponent whose represented (unencoded) value is the absolute different between the operand exponents. For example, if the operands are 1.5•2<sup>7</sup> and 1.125<sup>9</sup>, it provides the encoding for an exponent of 2. Of what use is that? Perhaps you are trying to make room to position the significands of the operands with a desired shift between them, but it is not clear how you will use this. With the available information, on the balance, I would say it is not a correct way of “equalizing exponents.”